# How to add Blender menu item in main menu?

Tags: menu, blender

Downloaded blender. How can I add menu item with blender icon in main menu?

Comment: Downloaded from where?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before you try to add it to the menu:

You should probably install the version of Blender that is available via the Software Centre:

Open the Software Center from the *Applications* menu and type "blender" into the search box in the upper right corner.

Or, alternatively, [**Click this Link**](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/blender) to install blender.

Blender will now be installed and in your menu.

---

Still, to add an application to the Menu right click on the main menu and select "Edit Menus":
[image: Main Menu]

From there, select "New item":

[image]

The command to start blender should be `blender`, choose your name and icon and put it wherever you want.